# Escape backslash in variable

Tags: shell, backslash

I am using sed to replace url's in a file, everything works fine just a hiccup when the url contains a '\'

exmaple url: http****://www.example.com/simi/icr

```
# variables
ICR_KEY=somekey
ICR_KEY_VAL="http\://www.example.com/simi/icr"
sed "s!${ICR_KEY}=.*!${ICR_KEY}=${ICR_KEY_VAL}!" properties > tmp
```

This replaces the URL, but the output does not contain the backslash from the variable value.

Comment: Pray tell, *why* does the URL contain a backlash?

Comment: This url is further fed to a java procedure which resides in oracle that's all i know... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both bash and sed interpret the backslash as escape character. Use single quotes to prevent this for bash, and double the backslash for sed:

```
ICR_KEY_VAL='http\\://www.example.com/simi/icr'
```

Comment: awesome, i tried double backslash and god knows what.. but never a single quote. Thanks much !!