# makefile determining order of latex input files

Tags: makefile, latex, pdflatex

I am trying to have a makefile controlling the generation of beamer presentations that are formed by adding parts (slides) that cover different topics. I want to be able to specify in the makefile the parts and their order, which can change for different presentations.

For instance, I may have different .tex files each with slides on different topics, say topicA topicB and topicC. Then at some stage I may want to make a presentation where I want a PDF containing first the slides concerning topicA and then the ones on topicB, while on a different time I may want to do another presentation where I want first the slides on topicC and then the ones on topicA. I would like to control the order and topics to include on a presentation on a makefile.

The solution I'm trying to implement consists in having a top latex file (say top.tex) that in the end would have a command (say "\slidesorder") whose content would be a series of \input's with the names of the files with the slides of the topics to include.

In summary, I have:

- top.tex (main latex file that near the end has the command \slidesorder )
- topicA.tex, topicB.tex and topicX.tex (latex files with the slides on each topic)

Then I've written the following makefile that is not working correctly:

```
ROOT = top

SLIDES := topicB topicA topicC
TO_INCL := $(foreach V,$(SLIDES),\input{$(V)})

all: $(ROOT).pdf

${ROOT}.pdf:  ${ROOT}.tex $(SLIDES:=.tex) 
    echo "\newcommand{\slidesorder}{$(TO_INCL)} \input{$(ROOT)}" | pdflatex
```

The idea would be that by changing the content of the SLIDES variable I would get different presentations from the same sources of slides. My knowledge of Latex and Make is very limited so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: if you were doing this by hand you'd append the line "\newcommand{\slidesorder} \input{topicB.tex} \input{topicA.tex} \input{topicC.tex}" to `top.tex`, then type "pdflatex top.tex", is that right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case, but my goal is to have a folder with the slide sources (the .tex files) and then I will have different folders for different specific presentations I will do based on part of these slides, each with its own makefile, that will build the specific presentation by issuing the adequate \newcommand . The above code is a simplification of this scenario just for better illustrating my problem with the makefile. If I add the \newcommand line to top.tex everything works perfectly.

Comment: OK, from the first answer to  [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487303/shell-escape-backslash-in-variable) I learned that the problem is not the makefile but escaping backslash in shell!

Answer (score 1):

OK, after the discovery of the problems with the backslash in the shell I've managed a  working solution:

```
ROOT = top

SLIDES := topicB topicA topicC
TO_INCL := $(foreach V,$(SLIDES),\input{$(V)})
TO_PDFLTX := '\\newcommand{\\slidesorder}{'$(TO_INCL)'} \\input{'$(ROOT)'}'

all: $(ROOT).pdf

${ROOT}.pdf:  ${ROOT}.tex $(SLIDES:=.tex) 
    echo $(TO_PDFLTX)| pdflatex
```